# PyVISA error reading from TCP/IP unless exact number of incoming bytes is specified

Tags: python, tcp, labview, pyvisa

I have some Python code for reading from a device, which returns a read error unless I specify exactly the number of bytes returned or fewer.  The following code successfully returns `SA-14212`, which is exactly 8 characters and is the correct response.  But we will not always know the correct length of the response in advance and replacing `data = session.read_bytes(8)` with `data = session.read_bytes(9)` or `data = session.read_bytes(1024)` or `data = session.read()` causes an error.

```
import pyvisa as visa

HOST = '192.168.0.15'
PORT = 7088
message = '*IDN?'

visa.log_to_screen()

# Open a TCPIP connection using VISA
resourceManager = visa.ResourceManager() 
dev = 'TCPIP0::' + HOST + '::' + str(PORT) + '::SOCKET'
session = resourceManager.open_resource(dev)
    
session.write(message)

data = session.read_bytes(8)
print(data.decode())

session.close()
```

Here are the error and proximate debugging statements for `data = session.read_bytes(9)`:

```
2023-12-02 01:17:01,872 - pyvisa - DEBUG - viWrite(1, b'*IDN?\r\n', 7, 'c_ulong(7)') -> 0
2023-12-02 01:17:01,872 - pyvisa - DEBUG - TCPIP0::192.168.0.15::7088::SOCKET - reading 9 bytes (last status None)
2023-12-02 01:17:01,887 - pyvisa - DEBUG - viRead(1, <ctypes.c_char_Array_9 object at 0x0000029043084CC0>, 9, 'c_ulong(8)') -> -1073807298
2023-12-02 01:17:01,887 - pyvisa - DEBUG - TCPIP0::192.168.0.15::7088::SOCKET - exception while reading: VI_ERROR_IO (-1073807298): Could not perform operation because of I/O error.
Buffer content: bytearray(b'')
```

The device is an obscure Fibre-Bragg-Grating demodulation device with very little documentation.  To my knowledge it uses no termination character for input or output
(changing it from `''` to `'\0'` or `'\n'` doesn't alter things).  I have looked up the error code here:
https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA00Z000000P6FmSAK
but it sheds no light.

We have separate working code using the Python socket library and it ostensibly does exactly the same as here: opens a TCPIP connection, writes a byte string, reads a response (into a buffer with 1024 characters).  Unfortunately the goal is a PyVisa implementation, not a raw sockets implementation.

Comment: How is it related to Labview? Can you read 1 byte at a time and handle the empty data exception?

Comment: @LiorBilia, on my system PyVisa is a wrapper for the National Instruments LabView VISA library (the debug statements above include a Labview error code).  Yes, I can read 1 byte at a time and handle the exception.  This is incredibly inefficient though, especially if data volumes are high.

Comment: Model? Make? You can try just \n, and not \r\n as command termination. If you have NI-MAX installed, try sending commands manually, and see if you get these errors. If you have an alternate hardware interface (RS232?,GPIB?) try using that, many SCPI over TCP implementations are buggy, including those from top tier vendors.

Comment: @LiorBilia Thank you.  At this point I am fairly certain it's just that the Labview library dumps what has been received if the connection is dropped before the requested or undefined number of bytes is received, and saner implementations like those in Python and C socket libraries give you what has been received up to the termination.  Reinforces my view that Labview is the devil's work!